# Transactions stuck using MySql 8.x connector

Tags: vb.net, mysql-connector

I hope you can help me. I have a vb.Net system running stable on MySql RDS 5.7 for a few years.
Due to the EOL of 5.7, we prepared the migration to MySql 8, and it is practically ready and fully tested.
But to minimize the migration process, we updated the project that used the 6.9.x connector (Mysql.Data.dll) to the 8.3.0 connector, which is backwards compatible with MySql 5.7.
However, we are facing a strange problem: with new connector, pointing to MySql 5.7, the behavior of transactions is different. With the new connector, transactions are getting stuck and not finishing correctly, generating a cascade effect that crashes the entire instance.
If I return the connector to 6.9.x the problem disappears.
Since the DB instance is exactly the same, I can't figure out how simply changing the connector could cause different behavior with transactions.
Some important information: some transactions may be causing problems even with the old connector, but simply changing the connector should not justify such different behavior.
I've tried several versions within 8.x (from version 8.0 to version 8.3) and it seems that they all have this problem.
I use the .net 4.6.2 framework.

Thank you and I hope you can help me!

i'm expecting same behavior using any .net MySql Connector and I'm afraid of this problems occurs in MySql Server 8.0.35.

Comment: Show us your code where you initiate and handle transactions (whether it's SQL `BEGIN WORK`/`COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK`, DTC, .NET `TransactionScope` or `MySqlTransaction`)